# Is there a way to find the names of the facets in a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add some curves to a ggplot with facets but I can not figure out how to correctly identify a particular panel with a particular name used for faceting.  For instance:

```
a <- data.frame(Surg=c("Surg1", "Surg2", "Surg3","Surg1", "Surg2", "Surg3"), 
           Times=c(23,45,12,45,7,12))
plota <- ggplot(a) +
  geom_histogram(aes(Times)) +
  facet_wrap(~Surg)
```

I can then use `ggplot_build(plota)` to get a lot of information but I can't seem to find where the name of a particular panel is found.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could extract the `data.frame` in `layout`

```
p1 <- ggplot_build(plota)
p1$layout$layout
  PANEL ROW COL  Surg SCALE_X SCALE_Y
1     1   1   1 Surg1       1       1
2     2   1   2 Surg2       1       1
3     3   1   3 Surg3       1       1
```

The 'layout' is a `data.frame` with the `PANEL` and the names in 'Surg'.  We just need to extract the 'Surg' column

```
p1$layout$layout$Surg
[1] "Surg1" "Surg2" "Surg3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the really quick response!  I think this is exactly what I'm looking for....After checking it out -- yes, this solves my problem.  Thanks, again.